# Ansible - Too much data in stdout

Tags: ansible

I have simple playbook:

```
- name: cats
  shell: cat userContent/lb.html | head -n1
  args:
    chdir: "{{jenkins2_service_directory}}"
  register: cat

- debug:
    msg: "{{cat}}"
```

But from yesterday on a few hosts output is strange:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -e target=eval-jenkins2

PLAY [eval-jenkins2] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [playground : cats] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [eval-jenkins2]

TASK [playground : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [eval-jenkins2] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "cat userContent/lb.html | head -n1",
        "delta": "0:00:00.008241",
        "end": "2024-02-20 12:22:17.562124",
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2024-02-20 12:22:17.553883",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "{'changed': True, 'end': '2024-02-19 22:27:15.515103', 'stdout': '{\\'changed\\': True, \\'end\\': \\'2024-02-19 22:24:14.047454\\', \\'stdout\\': \\'{\\\\\\'changed\\\\\\': True, \\\\\\'end\\\\\\': \\\\\\'2024-02-19 22:23:43.833081\\\\\\', \\\\\\'stdout\\\\\\': \\\\\\'{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'changed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': True, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\'end\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \\\\\\\\\\\\\\'2024-02-19 21:36:50.349584\\\\\\\\\\\\\\', \\\\\\\\\\\\\\'stdout\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \\\\\\\\\\\\\\'{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'changed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': True, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'end\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'2024-02-19 21:13:44.237671\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\', \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'stdout\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'changed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': True, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'end\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'2024-02-19 21:06:16.271822\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\', \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'stdout\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'changed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': True, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'end\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'2024-02-19 20:32:04.650843\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\', \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'stdout\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
...
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'failed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': False}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'], \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'stderr_lines\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': [], \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'failed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': False}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'], \\\\\\\\\\\\\\'stderr_lines\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': [], \\\\\\\\\\\\\\'failed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\': False}\\\\\\'], \\\\\\'stderr_lines\\\\\\': [], \\\\\\'ansible_facts\\\\\\': {\\\\\\'discovered_interpreter_python\\\\\\': \\\\\\'/usr/bin/python\\\\\\'}, \\\\\\'failed\\\\\\': False}\\'], \\'stderr_lines\\': [], \\'failed\\': False}'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
eval-jenkins2              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And it should be:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -e target=prod-jenkins2

PLAY [prod-jenkins2] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [playground : cats] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [prod-jenkins2]

TASK [playground : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [prod-jenkins2] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "cat userContent/lb.html | head -n1",
        "delta": "0:00:00.006767",
        "end": "2024-02-20 12:23:32.121463",
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2024-02-20 12:23:32.114696",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "off",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "off"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
prod-jenkins2              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds
```

How do you check why this is happening?

Eval-jenkins2 and prod-jenkins2 both are Centos7.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.3]
```

but I've also checked ansible via venv. Recently I was just testing playbooks, nothing was installed on the system and anyway it changed during some ansible run.

Comment: What is the content of `userContent/lb.html`? Can you show the output of `cat userContent/lb.html`?

Comment: In the second play you can see, there is also an additional line with a hostname. Nothing else. Simple file for switching F5 LoadBalancer.

Comment: Yesterday there were only 3 backslashes and additional data and today there is a lot of it. Rebooting the machine did not help.

Comment: @U880D you are right, the file is broken. I'd cat it and I saw the same output.

Answer (score 0):

A wrong assumption about the data. The file on the target host was broken. In another task, it was mistakenly overwritten.

```
    - name: "Modify /userContent/lb.html file on {{ target }} as on | switch F5 LB"
      become_user: "{{ jenkins2_user }}"
      become: true
      template:
        src: lb.html.j2
        dest: "{{ jenkins2_service_directory }}/userContent/lb.html"
      vars:
        lb_status: "on"
        lb_node: "{{ target }}"
```

when lb.html.j2 is:

```
{{ lb_status }}
{{ lb_node }}
```

Comment: And the problem occurred because of the precedence of variables. In another task I used also the lb_status variable.